# Get input value for country code with jquery [auto country by IP/intl-tel-input jquery library]

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I need to submit COUNTRY CODE to URL based on the selected country value.

Im using Intl-Tel-Input for this: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Here is HTML code:

```
<form id="redirform" method="GET" action="#link"> 
                                <div class="gtd-form-wrapper">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="country" name="country">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="phone" pattern="[0-9]*" id="phone" class="f w-input" data-value-missing="Use numbers only. No country code! No whitespaces!" required="required" placeholder="Phone">
                                </div> 

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="submit-button w-button gtd-form-submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Here is jQuery:

```
        var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
        window.intlTelInput(input, {
            initialCountry: "auto",
            geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
                $.get("https://ipinfo.io/", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
                var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                success(countryCode);
                });
            },
        });

        input.addEventListener('countrychange', function () {
                $('#country').val(iti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2);
            });

        $('#redirform').on('submit',function(){
        var $input = $(this).find("input[name=country]");
            $('#country').val(iti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2);
        });
```

Here is picture of what I have and what I need:
[PICTURE CLICK TO OPEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21dWM.png)

Comment: Where are you calling geoIpLookup function?

Comment: It doesn't submit country code to URL. I need to get ?country=LV , but instead it is ?country=  ....... aka BLANK.

Comment: Can you add the piece of code that handles the url navigation?

Comment: I don't really get it. There is method="GET", when u click submit button. It should get values from form. All the needed code is here.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do , where is this function : getSelectedCountryData?  try to be more detailed so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I said it is using Intl-Tel-Input plugin: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input here is documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to get the selected country value from the intl input.
You don't need to add country input in HTML.

```
    var intl = window.intlTelInput(input, {
        initialCountry: "auto",
        geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
            $.get("https://ipinfo.io/", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
            success(countryCode);
            });
        },
    });

    $('#redirform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var countryData = iti.getSelectedCountryData();

        var form = $('#form');
        form.append($("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "country").val(countryData.iso2));

        form.submit();
    });
```

while the form is submitting, there is a hidden input is created and the value is set, so you don't need to worry about it.

Because you have told you to need to get the country value into URL, the form will submit as GET because the method of the form is GET.

Hope this will help you. thanks.